# XPage does not render correctly

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

We have a database with anonymous access with a simple XPage on it.
After upgrading to Domino 10.0.1, it does not work correctly.
The design of the page is not rendered well and buttons do not work.

I get the following messages in the browser console (Chrome)
[image: error messages in Chrome]

When I follow the dojo.js:2 link, it refers to `https://<<server>>/xsp/.ibmxspres/dojoroot-1.9.7-u/dojo/dojo.js`
But when I open the link, I get the login page instead of the js page.

I already played with the XSP settings on compressed and optimised css/js; but with no luck.
I also added following parameters to the XSP properties without success:

```
xsp.error.disable.detection.set01=true
xsp.error.disable.0380=true
```

When I login, all works fine.

Please advise on how to make sure dojo and css are loaded when browsing anonymously.

Comment: Is the XPage itself marked as "Available to Public Access users"?

Comment: The ACL specifically allows Anonymous access. The XPage wasn't marked specifically, so I tried. Alas, without success.

Comment: Tom, my mistake. Anonymous access via ACL is just fine. "Available to Public Access users" is only necessary if anonymous have no access but "read public documents" in the ACL.

Comment: I just tested on 10.0.1 and I have no issues with anonymous access to an XPage

Comment: The server does not allow anonymous access but we are using HTTPPublicURLS in Notes.ini to open databases to grant anonymous access. Could that cause the issue?

Comment: Can you update your question with the value of HTTPPublicURLS. Do they still match the Dojo etc versions

Comment: The HTTPPublicUrls are only pointing to the nsf; not the dojo files. We will do some more testing on that.

Comment: The dojo files are not in the nsf

Comment: Did changing HTTPPublicUrls value solve it?

Comment: @PaulStephenWithers Haven't been able to test it yet. Issue is at a customer that I don't frequently visit. Although I have the impression that we have to include dojo files etc in HTTPPublicUrls in order to get it fixed.